# Editable Table in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been having trouble figuring out how to edit table items on a webpage, and post them back to the server.  (actually, in this case, I just want the user to select checkboxes, as though they are selecting multiple items, but that's just the implimentation).

The problem is that, while the view shows up on the webpage, in HttpPost, picSelections is null.

This is at the top of my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<CarShow.lmit_pics>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
<div style="width:100%; height:60px; ">
<input type="submit" value="Add Selected Photo(s) to Survey" />
</div>

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        var item = Model.ElementAt(i);
    <div style="width:296px; float:left">

            <div style="float:left; width:200px; margin-bottom:18px">

                @{string cropped = "../../../Content/Images/" + Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.picname).ToString() + "?" + Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.version).ToString();
                 }
                <img alt="picture" class="pic-size" src="@cropped" />
                <br />
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.brand)
            </div>

</div>
        }    
}
</div>
```

This is in the controller:

```
public ActionResult AddSurveyPic(string id)
{
   var validPicSummaries = (IEnumerable)(from x in db.lmit_pics where x.enabled == 1 select x);
   return View((IEnumerable)validPicSummaries);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSurveyPic(IEnumerable<CarShow_MVC.lmit_pics> picSelections)
{
        // Save data here
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the editable table inside a POST-able `<form>`?

Comment: I think so.  I just added more of the code.  I have not added the editable fields yet, but I presume that should not interfere with the post.  Maybe I did it wrong?

Comment: If there are no editable fields, there wont be anything encoded for posting to the controller action

Comment: Jason, I added an HTML.EditorFor on one of my fields, and got the same result.  I updated the view code above to reflect the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't write loops in your views. I would recommend you to use editor templates:

```
@model IEnumerable<CarShow.lmit_pics>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    <div style="width:100%; height:60px; ">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Selected Photo(s) to Survey" />
    </div>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
}
```

and then create a corresponding editor template which will automatically be rendered for each element of the model: `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/lmit_pics.cshtml`. Notice the name and location of the template which are important:

```
@model CarShow.lmit_pics

<div style="width:296px; float:left">
    <div style="float:left; width:200px; margin-bottom:18px">
        @{string cropped = "../../../Content/Images/" + Html.DisplayFor(x => x.picname).ToString() + "?" + Html.DisplayFor(x => x.version).ToString(); }
        <img alt="picture" class="pic-size" src="@cropped" />
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.brand)
    </div>
</div>
```

You might also want to read the [following article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) to better understand the naming conventions that the default model binder uses when binding collections and dictionaries.

Comment: `Don't write loops in your views` -- Really?  That was kind of the bread and butter of MVC1, or at least the butter.  Have things changed that much?

Comment: Yes, things have enormously changed with the introduction of strongly typed helpers and editor/display templates in ASP.NET MVC 2. It's since this moment that you no longer need to write loops in the views.

Comment: I'm so new to MVC, Editor templates are totally new to me.  The load time seems a lot faster now.  MVC is awesome!  One thing, though, the HttpPost is still not catching the result at all now.  I'll research this, but do you know offhand what else I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You mean that `picSelections` is still null in the POST action?

Comment: It works... sorry I made a change to HttpPost then changed it back and everything's fine now.  Your code worked, first try.  Thanks so much!